# How to handle parallel calls to a Python API?

Tags: python, api, parallel-processing

I wrote an API which which does some database operations with values requested by the API caller. How does this whole API system work when more than on person calls a function at the same time?

1. Do different instances of my API code start when a number of API calls are made?
2. If I need to handle like 2500 parallel API calls, what exact precaution (like paying attention to database load) do I need to take?

Comment: What is your API written in? What framework? django? Need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to call your python API from some other python code? If so then how is the parallelism achieved? Do you plan to spawn many threads, use your api in every thread?

Anyway it's worthwhile to take a look at `multiprocessing` module that allows one to create separate python processes. There are lots of `threading` modules that allow to parallelize code execution within the same process. But keep in mind that the latter case is a subject for Global Interpreter Lock - google for more info.

Comment: no no no// thats not what I am asking.. the python code is the python API. I am does python api handle parallel calls? Or its like every call to the python api would create a new intanse of the code.. .?

Comment: what does your python api look like?